# I'm the only admin but can't sudo in Mac

Tags: permissions, root, sudo, macos-sierra, sudoers

In my MacBook Pro, I'm the only admin user. I was feeling cumbersome when I need to type `sudo` when I pip install packages, so I try to make myself no need to do that by uncommenting `%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL` in `/etc/sudoers` file. But after I save it, I can no longer even use sudo! Every time I use it it'll give me `joseph is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.` message. And you know, in order to change `/etc/sudoers` file back I have to use `sudo`, so it's a catch 22 situation now.. How to fix it?

Comment: Make a copy of it, edit it and copy it back...

Comment: copy needs sudo permission too..

Comment: I mean copy it by dragging from Finder, then it will ask your admin password.

Comment: I indeed changed it but I still can't use sudo because it says "/etc/sudoers is owned by uid 501, should be 0"

Comment: So change the owner back to root, (`chown root:wheel /etc/sudoers`)...

Comment: it says "chown: /etc/sudoers: Operation not permitted"

Comment: Then change it in Finder by doing get info (cmd + i) on the file. It should be system = read only, wheel = read only, everyone = no access. If that doesn't work then run disk utility to repair your system permissions

Comment: there's no "system" and "wheel" users in the list. I guess I have to run disk utility? How to do that?

Comment: programming experience doesn't help fixing computers.

Comment: Sure it does, no idea why you would think that. I'm not trying to sound condescending but normally if you don't know what can happen as a result of messing with something you're unfamiliar with then it's probably a good idea not to mess with it. Disk Utility is an application, in the Utilities directory...

Comment: I'm not asking what it is - who doesn't know what it is - but what exactly I need to change there? And actually I surely have opened it and tried it already from some articles online, but it didn't work - that's why I'm asking you - what exactly the thing I should change? stating things too vague and expecting the other to know exactly what you think is not gonna help.

Comment: and exactly because I don't want to mess around with stuff I'm not familiar with I came here to ask for help. I don't know what can sound not condescending if yours is not.

Comment: anyway, I fixed things myself by creating a root user and recreated sudoer file there. Thanks for your previous help though, it indeed provides some inspirations - fyi, this is where programming experience help - a general problem solving ability - but not necessarily the exact experience on computer fixing.

Comment: What you're describing is computers 101 though, and it's not related to programming whatsoever. When I gave advice to change the permissions in Finder your reply was very vague in itself, so I'm not sure what you expect me to say. Give more information and maybe it will help those trying to help you.

Comment: you don't have to make people asking for help here feel dumb. that doesn't make you look smart. and I don't appreciate your help this way. Thanks for what you already have done and your time so far though.

Comment: You're welcome! I wasn't trying to make you feel *dumb* and I don't think I'm smarter than anyone else; I think you misinterpreted what I said, or you are reading into things way too much. Generally though, I think it's better if you expire all your options before asking for help and needing someone to hold your hand through the entire process. Figuring things out yourself I feel is usually the best way to learn; just my opinion though so take it for what it is... Also you should post your solution as an answer, since it might possibly help someone else in a similar predicament.someday :)